# Null component com.sun.web-8 in Java System Web Server 7.0

Tags: java

I have a JSP application host in JES 7.0 ,deployed through .war package, but the application can't be initialized due to below exception, could you please help on this ?

there are libs in WEB-INF folder

```
commons-logging1.1.jar
ejb.jar
jdbc2_0-stdext.jar
jms.jar
jmx.jar
jta.jar
junit.jar
servlet.jar


21/Oct/2010:10:36:29  failure  WebModule[/gpr]PWC1270: Exception starting filter trimFilter 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.cj.trim.trimFilter at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1507) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:221) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:333) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:89) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4324) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5118) at com.sun.webserver.connector.nsapi.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:235) at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1224) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:924) at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1224) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:520) at org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded.start(Embedded.java:917) at com.sun.enterprise.web.PwcWebContainer.onStartup(PwcWebContainer.java:70) at com.sun.webserver.connector.nsapi.WebContainer.start(WebContainer.java:491) at com.sun.webserver.init.J2EERunner.confPostInit(J2EERunner.java:304)  

21/Oct/2010:10:36:29  failure PWC1306: Startup of context /gpr failed due to previous errors 




21/Oct/2010:10:36:29  failure Null component com.sun.web-8:type=JspMonitor,name=jsp,WebModule=//xpdevbox/gpr,J2EEApplication=null,J2EEServer=none
```

Answer (score 1):

The real failure is due to the `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.cj.trim.trimFilter`

indicates that this class is not present in the web app's classpath. You seem to have defined that `Filter` in your `web.xml`

In the WEB-INF/lib you need `trimflt.jar` which can be downloaded from

http://www.servletsuite.com/servlets/trimflt.htm